# pandas copy numerical values from column based on categorical condition and put in new column

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

The purpose of this code is to:

1. Create a  dummy data set that contains 2 columns with 25 rows filled
   with values between 0 and 100.
2. Calculate the peaks and troughs of the data and put in a new column
   called value.
3. In order to plot the data and visualize the result I need numerical
   values, so I want to create 2 additional columns one called peak and
   trough containing the numerical values and to be located at the same
   row as peak or trough values in the value column.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import argrelmax, argrelmin

data = np.random.randint(0, 100,(25, 2))
df = pd.DataFrame(data , columns=['a', 'b'])

peak = argrelmax(data = np.array(df.b), axis=0, order=2, mode='clip')[0]
for x in peak:
  if x == df.index[x]:
    df.loc[x, 'value'] = 'peak'
    df.loc[x, 'peak'] = df.b.iloc[[x]]

trough = argrelmin(data = np.array(df.b), axis=0, order=2, mode='clip')[0]
for x in trough:
  if x == df.index[x]:
    df.loc[x, 'value'] = 'trough'
    df.loc[x, 'trough'] = df.b.iloc[[x]]
df
```

Here is the error:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 3   if x == df.index[x]:
> 4     df.loc[x, 'value'] = 'peak'
> ----> 5     df.loc[x, 'peak'] = df.b.iloc[[x]]
>
> 3 frames
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in
> _align_series(self, indexer, ser, multiindex_indexer)
>
> 1950             return ser.reindex(ax)._values    1951
> -> 1952         raise ValueError("Incompatible indexer with Series")    1953     1954     def _align_frame(self, indexer, df: ABCDataFrame):
>
> ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't looked much into the logic but I think the problem is the indexing here should be only 1 square bracket:

```
df.loc[x, 'peak'] = df.b.iloc[x]
```

same here

```
df.loc[x, 'trough'] = df.b.iloc[x]
```

Answer (score 0):

More optimized and easy way is to use `np.where`

```
peak = argrelmax(data = np.array(df.b), axis=0, order=2, mode='clip')[0]
df['peak'] = np.where(df.index.isin(peak), df.b, np.NaN)

trough = argrelmin(data = np.array(df.b), axis=0, order=2, mode='clip')[0]
df['trough'] = np.where(df.index.isin(trough), df.b, np.NaN)
```